# Change Camera Renderer Data via script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, render, lwrp

Does anyone know how to access and change the Renderer Data of Camera via script?

[image]

My purpose is this:

```
public bool ActiveDepth;
public Camera myCamera;
public RendererData renderClassic;
public RendererData renderDepth;

// if active get depth profile, else return to standard
void onGui()
{
    if(!ActiveDepth)
        myCamera.GetComponent<Renderer>().RendererData = renderClassic;
    else
        myCamera.GetComponent<Renderer>().RendererData = renderDepth;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Is this the default Camera component in Unity? What version of Unity is this?

Comment: yes. It's standard camera in Unity 2019.2 and lwrp (or urp).

Comment: yea, it's very strange, I'd either contact Unity Support (kinda pointless if you ask me) or try the 2019.3 Beta version, since they did several modifications to the LWRP

Comment: Beta's risk being unstable ... it's risky.
However the question remains on how to access that information and change it (which also turns out to be .asset)
On the manual it doesn't seem to be there.